# Getting question mark printed while writting to text

Tags: macros, openoffice.org

I am using openoffice calc macro to write to a text file, after converting hex to decimal, then using char function on the result. See below when i convert in openoffice using the function - converting '88' in hex. It is correctly displayed in the forumula result.

[image: char]

However if we open the text file after running the below macro, which does the same thing, '?' is displayed. How can i correct this and get the exact value printed in the text file?

```
Sub Sheet2

Dim AsciiString As String
Dim t As String
Dim DataArray As Variant
intFH = FreeFile()
Open "e:\Temp.txt" For Output As intFH
 t= "&H" & "88"
 AsciiString = AsciiString & chr(cdec(t))
 Print #intFH, AsciiString
close #intFH
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a solution for Openoffice (according to the text and tags of your question) or for Excel (according to the functions and vba code)?

Regarding OpenOffice/LibreOffice: your macro works with two slight modifications:

- Just change the type of Variable `t` to `Long`, and
- remove the `cdec()` function call - there's no such function in OpenOffice Calc, it's obviously an artefact from an Excel VBA macro.

Now, if you use ASCII codes (hex `5E` / decimal `94` for `^`, it will write `^` into the file:

```
Sub Sheet2
    Dim AsciiString As String
    Dim t As Long
    intFH = FreeFile()
    Open "/tmp/Temp.txt" For Output As intFH
    t= "&H" & "5E"
    AsciiString = chr(t)
    Print #intFH, AsciiString
    close #intFH
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, This formula gives "ˆ" as the result. Formula is =CHAR(HEX2DEC("88")). However even after i change the type of t to long in my original code, I get a question mark in the text file.

Comment: I suppose this is due to the **`cdec()`** function you're applying to the hex string. AFAIK there's no such formula in openoffice - this is why i asked: do you need a excel-based solution or a openoffice-based solution? My solution (without `cdec()`) works fine with openoffice. Next point is: do you need **plain ASCII** encoding or ISO encoding? `&H5E` is ASCII hex for `^`.

Comment: The charcter you have used/displayed, is =CHAR(94). I am talking about =CHAR(136), and that should be printed as ascii encoded, in the text file, using openoffice.

Comment: Yes, since 94 is 5E in hex, and it's the character used in your question. **`Char(136)`** without stating which encoding to use is meaningless, since the result of **`Char(x)`** with `x > 127` [depends on the individual environment](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_CHAR_function): "_CHAR uses your system's character mapping (for example iso-8859-1, iso-8859-2, Windows-1252, Windows-1250) to determine which character to return. Codes greater than 127 may not be portable._" This is why you should prefer the 7-bt ASCII alternative.

Comment: And again: please note that **HEX2DEC is a Excel function, not a OpenOffice funtion**. It may work for compatibility reasons when opening xls files with Calc, but to define openoffice-related issue, you should stick with openoffice.

Comment: I have to get GetEncoding(1252), which is the encoding. Do you have any suggestions, i can print this using openoffice. In vb System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytes)